# Best way to track how many times a button is clicked per day per user in an Android app?

Tags: android

I have 1000 DAU of my one of my Android apps. I want to track how many times a specific button in my app is clicked per day per user. I currently have Fabric Answers Analytics integrated int the app. Whats the best ways to store the data inside the app and then send it to analytics so that I can track the data daily.

Answer (score 1):

You can save user clicks in `SharedPreference`. Then at the end of day, you can send that count to Fabric logs.

Use this code to send count on Fabric.

```
int userClick = // get this from `SharedPreference`.
final int PRIORITY_ERROR = 6;
Crashlytics.log(PRIORITY_ERROR, "User click count", userClick );
```